# kind of instance variable changed in method

Tags: ruby, variables

```
class Appthin
    @fileDir = ["a","b"]
    puts @fileDir.class
    def findclass
        puts @fileDir.class
        checkFiles(@fileDir)
    end
end
```

input

```
Array
NilClass
```

why they are different, it confused me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because variables starting with an `@` symbol are instance variables, but when you're first calling it, there isn't an instance of Appthin initialized.

When you refer to an instance variable, it selects `self` and sets an instance variable for that.

If you're calling an instance variable from *the body of your class*, then `self` is the class itself, which is an instance of Class, but not an instance of Appthin.

---

The solution to your problem depends on what you're trying to do:

If you want to set a variable in the class body, which is accessible to all instances of the class, I'd use a constant.

```
class Appthin

  FILE_DIR = ['a', 'b']

  def find_class
    puts FILE_DIR
  end

end
```

If you're trying to set a variable belonging to a specific instance of Appthin, which can then be changed, set it in the initialize method:

```
class Appthin

  def initialize
    @file_dir = ['a', 'b']
  end

  def find_class
    puts @file_dir
  end

end
```

Comment: Why are you not using class variables? @@?

Comment: @rajagopalan I’ve got used to never using class variables because they’re not thread-safe. If you’re using a rack-mounted framework, like Rails. Then you can have differing values for class variables on different processes. This sometimes leads to unexpected values between one call and the next.